# PostgreSQL - Joining 3 tables returning too many results

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have 3 tables:

```
Advancements
  id

Advancement_Requirements
  advancement_id,
  requirement_id

Requirements
  id
  description
```

I want to get all of the `requirments.descriptions` for a certain `advancement.id`.  I am able to do this, but I have to use `DISTINCT`, which I do not want to do.  If I don't use `DISTINCT`, I get pages and pages of results.  Here is the query that I am running that works. Please tell me how to get my results without `DISTINCT`.

```
select distinct(requirements.description)
from requirements 
   inner join advancement_requirements on requirements.requirement_id = advancement_requirements.requirement_id 
   inner join advancements on advancement_requirements.advancement_id = 1;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `distinct` is ***not*** a function. "*What am I doing wrong*" - try to remove the parenthesis around the column. `(some_column)` is indeed something different than `some_column` in Postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your are trying to accomplish but my guess is that you try to join tables and you have a search criteria. So you should do something like this.

```
select 
requirements.description
from requirements 
inner join advancement_requirements on requirements.requirement_id = advancement_requirements.requirement_id 
inner join advancements on advancement_requirements.advancement_id = advancements.id
WHERE advancements.id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not associating the Advancements table in your join so it just return a result for each requirement times a Advancements register.

```
select requirements.description from requirements inner join advancement_requirements on requirements.requirement_id = advancement_requirements.requirement_id inner join advancements on advancement_requirements.advancement_id = advancements.id
where advancements.id = 1;
```

Comment: I believe the query you posted is my exact query. How do I go about referring to my `Advancement` table correctly to make this work like it should?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to retrieve the distinct, in this case it´s not necessary

Answer (score 0):

If you have foreign keys and a `UNIQUE` (or `PRIMARY KEY`) constraint on `(advancement_id, requirement_id)` in `Advancement_Requirements` (the typical layout for such an n:m relationship), then this simple query would not need `DISTINCT`.

```
SELECT r.description
FROM   requirements r
JOIN   advancement_requirements ar USING (requirement_id)
WHERE  ar.advancement_id = 1;
```

Or there is information missing in your question.